# Web tool to simulate a web service response?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, testing

We are developing a product which will communicate with a REST web service. The service is not ready yet, but we know the interface.

We need to test our product without having actual service running.

e.g.

Our program sends request:
`http://server:port/user_details?user_id=123`

We are expecting to receive the following json:

```
{
    "user_id": 123,
    "user_first_name": John,
    "user_last_name": "Doe",
    "key": dG4fdF33rWf,
}
```

Im quite new to web services programming, so how do I emulate the response?

Is there any web tool where I can hardcode the json and call url, and provide a response after hitting `Send` button, or anything like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [MyJSON](http://myjson.com/).

It is a extremely simple online tool that takes a valid JSON as input and gives you a callable API that will return the same input JSON when called.

However, it needs keys and values in double quotes(as String), but that it not going to affect your response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Open Source version of [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) it supports Rest and if i am correct Jason(Pro)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WSSimulator](https://github.com/CognitiveJ/wssimulator) - Will give you what you are looking for.